# Android screen flips on usb keyboard connection

Tags: android, rotation, screen, orientation

I am using a portrait (native) display in landscape mode by using setprop ro.sf.hwrotation 90 in KitKat and it is working well.  The problem is that the screen momentarily flips/twists before going to the correct orientation when a USB keyboard is connected or disconnected.  The aspect ratio is momentarily distorted as well (e.g. clock becomes an oval).  The distortion only persists for a moment - but something is not correct.

This twist doesn't occur unless the ro.sf.hwrotation property is used - so I'm thinking that someplace in the Android source that needs to take it into account isn't.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can try handling the `keyboard` configuration change yourself, and that'll stop the activity from being recreated and causing the momentary distortion (see [docs here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange))

Comment: Thanks, I'd traveled a bit of that path already - I'm looking for a mod to the Android source so that the system handles this correctly.  I'm not so concerned with the activity recreation.  I edited the question to clarify.